# Is there any way to make python act like a game controller?

Tags: python, gamecontroller

I want to control games with python. I need python to act like a game controller and do what i code.
I couldn't find things about this. I'm waiting for your help. Thanks.

edit : I pretty much did it with using PyvJoy library and vJoy software. Its now possible python to act like game controller and press keys. This can be useful while developing machine learning apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example code I used a while ago in order to read inputs from an xbox controller hooked-up via the USB port and use them inside Python:
[my GitHub](https://github.com/UnnamedMoose/DIYROV/blob/master/Software/controlInterface/controllerInterface.py)

It relies on the pyGame module:
https://www.pygame.org/news